# What's with Gmail's upper-left corner?

Tags: gmail

I didn't notice this **small corner** before, but it is small, so I have no idea when it started. It resembles the corner of a piece of paper when we fold it.

This is a screenshot of how it looks like:

[image: gmail-corner]

Removing the other code, the corner appears like this:

[image: gmail-corner-only]

The remaining code is an iframe, with this code (ellipses indicate more code):

`<iframe src="https://hangouts.google.com/webchat/load?prop=gmail(...)" (...) id="gtn-roster-iframe-id"></iframe>`

Since Hangouts are mentioned, and I'm still using the *[old chat](https://support.google.com/chat#topic=4509880)* in this account, I decided to check my second account, in which I have Hangouts enabled:

[image: gmail-corner-hangouts]

Does anyone know why this happens? Does it have any purpose? Will it ever change, after some action? Is the *page* tearing, because of how *old* the chat is?!

---

Additional info: I am using Firefox in Mac, and this happens even in Private Browsing. I tried with Safari, and the same corner appears in Private Browsing as well. Using Safari's User Agent "Switcher", the behaviour is the same in every available browser (also in Private Browsing). I don't have extensions or plug-ins in any of the browsers. I also installed Chrome, and the same happened even in Incognito Mode.

---

Update: The linked page now states that

> Google Chat was officially shut down on June 26, 2017.

I was now forced to Hangouts, which made the "corner" disappear.

Comment: I can confirm you that under Linux/Firefox/hangsout enabled I cannot see that corner. I cannot find even with CTRL-SHIFT-C (the inspector). Try to see the (whole) code of the page in which you find it. Maybe there is some commented code from which you can guess something.

Comment: @Hastur I don't see it neither, when accessing through my Hangouts-enabled account. I don't find anything with the same id (`gtn-roster-iframe-id`) in the source of that account. But the first account, it appears under the main `<body>` tag, with that id, and with the source that I mentioned in the post. The `#document` header has many scripts, and then `<base href="https://hangouts.google.com/webchat/u/0/">` in the end, which by itself returns a 404. Its body also contains several references to "hangouts".

Comment: I don't see the "small corner icon" on an account with the old chat in a Chromebook. Try in incognito mode with all the extensions disabled and share with us if the icon is still there.

Comment: I cannot see the icon on the upper left corner of Gmail using Firefox on OSX. I tried also to search for it through the source code.

Comment: @VasilisKosmas But do you know if you have Hangouts enabled? Because if you have, that appears to be the expected behaviour.

Comment: I'm just posting here to confirm that I'm seeing the same issue, that it appears to be new for me as of today, and that I also use the old chat setting. Hopefully someone can find some sort of explanation for this.

Comment: Are you running in a VM by chance. There is a related question here with a similar issue,  Unfortunately no answer to this question. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/234841/os-x-yosemite-in-vmware-has-transparent-squares-in-window-corners

Comment: @tyelford Nope, the browsers are running directly in OS X (in a MacBook).

Comment: It doesn't look like this has been tried yet. Is that 'corner' still there if you change or disable your Gmail theme?

Comment: @Folk Yes, the `iframe id="gtn-roster-iframe-id" name="gtn-roster-iframe-id" src="https://hangouts.google.com/webchat/load?...` is still there, with any theme or image background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a not-very-well-hidden iframe for the old-style Gmail chat. Considering how old the old Gmail chat is, and that you're not seeing it with the more modern (but now still possibly outdated) Hangouts, it just seems like a bit of forgotten code that wasn't as well-crafted as the usual Google code we see.

I don't think it is anything special.

Comment: I guess we'll never for sure... For now, this seems to be the best answer